# When using Postgresql user defined function, how can I save some memory between mutiple calls?

Tags: function, postgresql

I have defined a function in C of Postgresql.

```
select concat_text(name, address) from talbe_name;
```

In fact, I want to malloc some memory to store common information when the shared library has been loaded, then when every row returns, I can use the memory. How can I remember something across rows?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Are you aware that there is already a `concat()` function in Postgres? And a `concat_ws()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! I have found the answer.  _PG_fini()

Comment: why are you trying to keep private memory? will that be safe if I do  `select concat_text( concat_text('mr ',name), concat_text('@',address)) from talbe_name;`

Comment: @Jasen concat_text is just a example, I really want to ask how to save privacy memory, thanks~